# 3D Matplotlib plotting inaccuracy for very small distances

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

This is an inaccuracy found in matplotlib 3D plotting for very small distances (let me know if I've done anything wrong).

```
print("[TEST] Plotted vector from "+str(M_pos[0])+" "+str(M_pos[1])+" "+str(M_pos[2])+" TO "+str(M_pos[0]+i.E[0])+" "+str(M_pos[1]+i.E[1])+" "+str(M_pos[2]+i.E[2]))
ax.quiver(M_pos[0], M_pos[1], M_pos[2], (M_pos[0]+i.E[0]), (M_pos[1]+i.E[1]), (M_pos[2]+i.E[2]))
```

Those two lines above (in a greater project, but those two are the most important because they show that the six variables printed and plotted are the same, create the following output:

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6SCO.png)

Even though the vector is clearly plotted from 1, 1, 1 to 0.98, 0.98, 0.98, the vector seems to be facing away from the origin in the 3D graph. Is this a well-known bug already, or are my lines of code off for any reason?

Comment: Quiver takes x,y,z,u,v,w not x,y,z,x1,y1,z1

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! And also Jody beat me to it.

My code read:

```
ax.quiver(M_pos[0], M_pos[1], M_pos[2], (M_pos[0]+i.E[0]), (M_pos[1]+i.E[1]), (M_pos[2]+i.E[2]))
```

But it should have read

```
ax.quiver(M_pos[0], M_pos[1], M_pos[2], (i.E[0]), (i.E[1]), (i.E[2]))
```

Because I assumed the quiver pointed from the point x,y,z to point x2,y2,z2 -- all relative to the origin. However, the last three values are actually determined RELATIVE TO point x,y,z. So to plot a given vector x,y,z to given point x2,y2,z2, one would actually plot x, y, z to point x2-x, y2-y, z2-z. This makes a lot more sense.